# How to get embedded http from href in html script - scrapy

Tags: python, html, scrapy

I'd like to get the embedded http link from this html script.
I'm an a scrapy shell for https://www.brunningandprice.co.uk/architectbath/
Then if I use response.css('p.mb-0 a::attr(href)').get()
I only get the '/architectbath/menus/' rather than the full http as pictured.
Does anyone know what I have to do differently to get this?
Unfortunately I can't just add this onto the url I already have.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Read about [urljoin()](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.urljoin).

```py
scrapy shell "https://www.brunningandprice.co.uk/architectbath/"

In [1]: partial_url = response.css('p.mb-0 a::attr(href)').get()

In [2]: partial_url
Out[2]: '/architectbath/menus/'

In [3]: absolute_url = response.urljoin(partial_url)

In [4]: absolute_url
Out[4]: 'https://www.brunningandprice.co.uk/architectbath/menus/'
```